# Show that $f(rx)=(f(x))^r$ for all $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ if $f(x+y)=f(x).f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x).f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=1$ then show that $f(rx)=(f(x))^r$ for all $r\in \mathbb{Q}$.

**Here is what I tried**

let $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers p and q

without loss of generality let $p>0$

$f(rx)=f(p\frac{x}{q})=f(\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}...\frac{x}{q})=(f(\frac{x}{q}))^p$

Now, I am stuck in how to prove $(f(\frac{x}{q}))^p=(f(x))^r$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(f(\frac{x}{q}))^p=(f(\frac{x}{q}))^{qr}=(f(x))^r$

since $f(x)=f(\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}+\cdots+\frac{x}{q})=f(\frac{x}{q})^q$

Comment: ohhh! now it seems pretty obvious thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShivamM if you are certain that all your doubts are cleared and you find this as the best possible and most useful answer for your query, then please click the check mark beside the answer in order to accept the answer. Please note that if you get multiple answers to a question, then you can accept only one of them. Accepting the answer gets the question off the “unanswered questions” list. However if you wish to wait for a more detailed answer, then you are more than welcome to do so.